# Using static resource in test class in order to test HTTP callout. Seems broken after update 1st of january

Tags: static-resources, httprequest, httpcalloutmock

I'm using static resource in the code below to mock a `httpcallout` response.
It seems like the update 1st of january did break the link - has anyone else experienced same issues?

My question is then - how can I now reference static resource in the multimock.setStaticResource method?
I receive an

> "ERROR System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to
>   SObject".

When trying to iterate and assign from the results from the mock.

```
MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock multimock = new MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock();
multimock.setStaticResource('https://xxxxxx/', 'xmlContactMatch');
multimock.setStatusCode(200);
multimock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, multimock);
```

Comment: Still not clear what kind of issue did you receive. Which error/exception did you get?

Comment: in that case, can you ensure that static resource is available and have correct name? as well as find at which line error occurs (f.e. adding dummy system.debug methods line by line and see where it fails?)

Comment: looks like you query not returning any record that's why you are getting error.

Comment: @Ratan - I know - But I'm asking if the update (serving static resources differently) could have something to do with it?

Comment: @kurunve - Can you elaborate how I can verify if the static resource is available in the test class?

Comment: On what line does the exception occur?

Comment: update this question with complete code. because List has no rows for assignment to SObject is coming from somewhere else not from the code you have posted.